# Let $\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=xe^{-x}$. Find $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{y}{x}$

Tags: calculus

> Let $$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=xe^{-x}$$ Find $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{y}{x}$$

I have tried to separate variables and integral both side of the function. However, it seems impossible.

Could any one give a quick solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use the asterisk `*` for multiplication. This symbol stands for convolution in mathematics. If you must add a multiplication symbol, use `\cdot` instead. But in this case, it is not needed. I edited your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quation will be an exact one if we use the integrating factor $\mu(x)=1/x, x\neq0$. So we have $d(y/x)=\exp(-x)$ and then $(y/x)=-e^{-x}+C$. Now can you find your answer?

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide details and final solution so that I can check my answer and others can learn from your example.Also,I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Nicely done, as usual!

Answer (score 1):

$y=-xe^{-x} +cx$
integrating factor = $e^{\int\frac{-1}{x}dx}$ proceed as mentioned here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor